# Does spring integration's tcp-inbound-channel-adapter and tcp-connection-factory have failover support?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I have a simple tcp client using spring integration that takes in a message, and writes it to file.

I want the client to connect by default to thing.input.primary.host, but in the event of a connection failure, I want it to reconnect to thing.input.secondary.host, and then send the message on like normal; is there support in spring integration for this behavior?

Edit: for clarity.  What I'd like to do, is to have it switch from thingClient to thingClientSecondary, if thingClient fails.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
       xmlns:int-ip="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip"
       xmlns:int-file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration          http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip       http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip/spring-integration-ip.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file     http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd">

    <int-ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter
            id="thingInGateway"
            connection-factory="thingClientPrimary"
            channel="fileOutputChain"
            client-mode="true"
            auto-startup="true"
            retry-interval="1000"/>

    <int-ip:tcp-connection-factory
            id="thingClientPrimary"
            type="client"
            host="${thing.input.primary.host}"
            port="${thing.input.primary.port}"
            deserializer="thingSerializer"
            serializer="thingSerializer"
            socket-support="thingSocketSupport"
            so-keep-alive="true"
            using-nio="true"/>

    <int-ip:tcp-connection-factory
            id="thingClientSecondary"
            type="client"
            host="${thing.input.secondary.host}"
            port="${thing.input.secondary.port}"
            deserializer="thingSerializer"
            serializer="thingSerializer"
            socket-support="thingSocketSupport"
            so-keep-alive="true"
            using-nio="true"/>
    <int:chain input-channel="fileOutputChain" >
        <int-file:outbound-channel-adapter directory="${thing.output.directory}"/>
    </int:chain>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

No; simply define a second channel adapter that uses the other factory and the same channel; then any data coming in on either port will go to the same place.

"Failover" is an unusual term on the server side. Normally, clients fail over when a server connection is lost.

On the server side, we are passive and the term "failover" makes no sense here.